# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am making an api in node js I have my mysql database, for the tests I use postman but I get the following error

I have inserted data in my table so I want to recover it

Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

this is the code of the connection to the database

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'tienda',

})

async function getConnection() {
    try{
        const connection = await pool.getConnection();
        return connection;
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
module.exports = {getConnection};
```

This code is from my get request where it sends me the error about the query I hope you can help me I do not understand what the error is

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const pool = require('./database')

app.get('/producto', async  (req, res) => {
    try{
        const  conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto";
        const resultado = await conn.query(consulta);
        res.status(200).json(resultado);
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});

app.post('/nuevoProducto', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const query = 'insert into producto value (?)';
    const resultado = conn.query(query, [req.body.name]);
    res.status(200).json(resultado);
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server on port', 3000);
})
```

error obtained
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: have you tested if a connection is possible with that data?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, sorry. I'm new, how would I do it?

Comment: the mysql client(mysql -u root -p root) or my workbench when you like a gui. Also you can try to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok, I already tried to get them in the interface (127.0.0.1:3000/product) but I don't get anything in the path the server stops and sends me the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined. I followed the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhRtAYTF6vk)

Comment: you should check the mysql error log if the server is running then the comand is called `mysql -u root -p root`nothing more to see if you can connect localhost and port 3306 are default values and

Comment: if it connects but does not return data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227360/discussion-between-manuel-and-nbk).